# Fastest way to read 3 bytes at a given pointer address?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, bitmap, int

I'm currently reading the pixel data of a bitmap, using the `BitmapData` available after locking the bitmap. The method I'm using reads each color byte seperately, and would be slower than reading a 4-byte `int` directly at the given pointer. But unfortunately my bitmap is 24bpp, meaning there are 3 bytes per pixel, not 4. So is there a way to read just 3 bytes quickly and cast it into an `int` at a given pointer address?

```
// read pixel color
byte* Pix = (byte*)bmpScan0 + (y * bmpStride) + (x * 3);
byte R = *(Pix + 2);
byte G = *(Pix + 1);
byte B = *(Pix);
int RGB = ((int)R << 16) | ((int)G << 8) | (int)B;
```

Comment: @MitchWheat Ah, very good point; bitmap pixel formats are all over the bloody place wrt endianess...

Comment: Your sample code is not aligned with what you are asking - it shows reading 3 bytes into separate variables instead of `int` with masking 8 highest bits... Also consider showing a bit more code - the one you have look like doing way to much math for getting next byte.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I've updated my code to show what I need to achieve.

Comment: Doesn't look like C# to me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of multiple operations - reading, masking, etc - you can read a full int at the pixel's address and mask out the extra byte.

```
int Pix = *(int*)((byte*)bmpScan0 + (y * bmpStride) + (x * 3)) & 0x00FFFFFF;
```

Depending on your endianness you might need to shift down instead of masking, and your color components may be reversed - BGR instead of RGB.

Oh, and you'll probably have some speed issues due to reading from memory that is not aligned to a 4-byte boundary.  You can get around those, but the solutions are often worse than the original problem.

Comment: +1. I believe this is correct approach (obviously no computation of "current" pixel is needed as `+=3` should do "move next" thing)... But @Geotarget already dismissed this approach in JerKimball's answer - so unclear what OP is lookng for.

Comment: The OP dismissed the answer because it didn't read the 3 bytes with 1 line of code. I didn't really need the R/G/B split bytes. I just used it because I had no other choice.

Comment: @Geotarget - I figured it was something like that.

Answer (score -1):

You mean something like:

```
int foo = *(some pixel address in memory);
byte R = (byte)(foo & 0xff0000 >> 16);
byte G = (byte)(foo & 0x00ff00 >> 8);
byte B = (byte)(foo & 0xff);
```

Edit: shall leave this answer unedited to maintain continuity in other comments, but no longer applicable based on edits to the question itself. :)

Comment: My code is already faster than this method. I'm looking for something *even* faster.